# How do I detect "ERROR:SCHEMA-INDEX-MISMATCH" in Solr?

Tags: solr

How do I find documents in my index that have a SCHEMA-INDEX-MISMATCH?  I have a number of these that I am finding them by trial-and-error.  I want to query for them.

The results that I get have "ERROR:SCHEMA-INDEX-MISMATCH" in a field.  An example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="12.993319">
        <doc>
            <float name="score">12.993319</float>
            <str name="articleId">ERROR:SCHEMA-INDEX-MISMATCH,stringValue=555</str>
            <str name="articleType">Knowledge Base</str>
            <str name="description">Moving to another drive Question: How can I ....</str>
            <str name="id">article:555</str>
            <str name="title">Moving to another drive</str>
            <str name="type">article</str>
        </doc>
    </result>
</response>
```

If it matters, my query is along the lines of `http://server/solr/select?q=id:%22article:555%22`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "type" of articleId?

I had issues with a date field and due to a defect in indexing program, I had 'ERROR:SCHEMA-INDEX-MISMATCH".  Since these are values out side the bounds of a normal date, I was able to find them by the query - "Not myDateFieldType:[0001-01-01T00:00:00Z NOW]" .

If you are able to craft this type of query, depending on your data type, you should be able to find these values.

Comment: articleId is an int.  I was able to get use your query to figure it out: I just queried for type:article AND NOT articleId:[0 TO 100000] and I seem to get all the mismatches.

Comment: I want to change type from string to long and on changing it shows this error. and if changes than also it behaves like string. so what's the solution?

Comment: You have to reindex.  If you dont have the original data,  use original solr index as source.  I cant think of another solution.